# How to integrate $\frac1{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to calculate $$\int\frac1{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}dx?$$
The integrand is$$\frac1{1+\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}}=\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}}$$
$$=\frac12\frac{(\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x})+(\sqrt{\cos x}-\sqrt{\sin x})}{\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}}$$
$$=\frac12\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}-\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}}\right).$$

Now I am facing problem to calculate $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}-\sqrt{\sin x}}{\sqrt{\cos x}+\sqrt{\sin x}}dx.$$ Please help me out.

Comment: Try $u(x) = \tan(x)$ and use the relation $\sec^2(x) = \tan^2(x) + 1$ to start.

Comment: $u = \tan x $ then partial fractions

Comment: If you do $u=\tan x,$ there remains a square root. Better follow the link above.

Comment: Similar question is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875014/evaluation-of-int-frac-sqrt-sin-x-sqrt-sin-x-sqrt-cos-xdx/4746225#4746225